# Help with diophantine equation: $m^2 -2n^2 = 10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I need to find integer solutions for m^2 -2n^2 = 10. I've tried factoring but I couldn't find anything that worked. Does anyone have tips for problems like this?

Comment: What have you tried? EG Did you test values of $m = 1$ to (say) 50 to find any solutions?

Comment: See [Pell's equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation) and its generalized form.

Comment: I didn't get any solutions trying small cases of m, but I tested for parity and found that m must be even. So I simplified to 2x^2 -n^2 = 10 where m=2x.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $2x^2-n^2=\color{red}5$?

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811620/integer-solutions-for-x2-2y2-10)